# WPF app's design need to be fixed (auto resize/locate controls when window size changed)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a task where I got a WPF project done with C#, and I have to fix its pre-existing design. I have to say that I'm really new to WPF and XAML pages, and I couldn't figure out how to make a good page design, and how to locate a control in a way it re-allocates/resizes it self when window size changes, so could you please point me in the right direction?

Desired design:
[image: Design]

My main problem now is that labels and checkboxes in the bottom of the design disappear when I use a very big screen ()
Here is my XAML code (I included here only controls that matters, not the whole design for sure) :
labels and checkboxes disappearing:

```
               <Grid Margin="892,0,0,0">
                    <Label x:Name="lblPrevious" Content="Previous" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="55" Cursor="Hand" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="25,43,0,-30"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lblNext" Content="Next" Cursor="Hand" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="284,43,-6,-30"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbGood" Content="Good" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="18" Margin="83,63,0,-43"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbNotsure" Content="Not sure" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="18" Margin="156,63,0,-43"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbBad" Content="Bad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="18" Margin="244,63,0,-43"/>
                </Grid>
```

Complete code:

```
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,32,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="227*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="979*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="StatusIndicator"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label x:Name="lblStatusText"
                        Content="{Binding CurrentBrowser.StatusText, FallbackValue=Status Text}"
                        Padding="5,1" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Label x:Name="lblSecurityStatus"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                    Padding="5,2"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    UseLayoutRounding="True" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,600,0,0">
                <Rectangle Margin="0,10,0,-2">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF313130" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.31" Color="#FFD8D8CF" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF757672" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.203" Color="#FFD8D8CF" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.547" Color="#FFBABAAF" />
                            <GradientStop Color="White" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Grid Margin="892,0,0,0">
                    <Label x:Name="lblPrevious" Content="Previous" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="55" Cursor="Hand" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="25,43,0,-30"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lblNext" Content="Next" Cursor="Hand" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="284,43,-6,-30"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbGood" Content="Good" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="18" Margin="83,63,0,-43"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbNotsure" Content="Not sure" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="18" Margin="156,63,0,-43"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbBad" Content="Bad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="18" Margin="244,63,0,-43"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <!--  REGION // Find Bar Controls //  -->
            <Label x:Name="label1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="28"
                Margin="12,2,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Find:" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtSearchTerm"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Width="130"
                Height="23"
                Margin="53,4,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkMatchCase"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="16"
                Margin="141.149,8,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Match Case" Grid.Column="1" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkWholeWord"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="16"
                Margin="239.149,8,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Whole Word" Grid.Column="1" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkSearchBackwards"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="16"
                Margin="345.149,8,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Search Backwards" Grid.Column="1" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkHiLitAll"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="16"
                Margin="544.149,8,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="HiLite All Occurrences" Grid.Column="1" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkWrapSearch"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="16"
                Margin="472.149,8,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button x:Name="btnFind"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Width="60"
                Height="23"
                Margin="189,4,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Find Next" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Button x:Name="btnFindPrevious"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Width="100"
                Height="23"
                Margin="27.149,5,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="Find Previous" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Border x:Name="NewTabButton"
                Width="28"
                Height="26"
                Margin="0,154,105,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1">
                <Image x:Name="btnNewTab"
                    ToolTip="Add New Tab" Margin="0,-25,0,25">
                    <Image.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                    </Image.LayoutTransform>
                </Image>
            </Border>
            <Grid Margin="5,10,885,515" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <ListBox x:Name="lstBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="316"/>
            </Grid>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbHeader1" IsChecked="True" Content="RB1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbHeader2" Content="RB2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbHeader3" Content="RB3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbHeader4" Content="RB4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnExport" Content="Export" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DGV" Grid.Column="1" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="332,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="637" Height="103" Panel.ZIndex="1" RowBackground="#FFC6C6C6" FontWeight="Bold" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" MinColumnWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header=" "/>
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="URL" Width="295"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Width="79"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 2" Width="83"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 3" Width="79"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 4" Width="79"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: If you want to maybe provide a visual of what you want it to look like, we can re-write your layout real quick so you can learn from it moving forward.

Comment: Ok will provide it in few minutes :). Thx!

Comment: Hey Chris, just added preview of the desired design.

Comment: Ok, I'm about to leave work for the day but will be back on in a few hours and will sort ya out later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's an example. Honestly I just free-handed it in Kxaml real quick and didn't even bother loading it in a designer, but it should be pretty on point with what your image shows and displays some better practice concepts to help cut down your xaml clutter, as well as promotes an intuitive tab order and less unnecessary rendering properties etc.

Hope it helps, let me know if you have any questions etc. I tried to leave lots of comments to kind of guide you along the DOM.

Cheers!

```
<Grid Margin="0,32,0,0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Your Top elements -->
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <!-- The Center white space -->
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <!-- The gray gradient bar with a fixed height -->
    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    <!-- The footer elements -->
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <!-- The Status Text stuff -->
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <!-- Let's set some children properties for inheritance -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>

  <!-- Begin Row 0 -->
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

    <ListBox x:Name="lstBox"/>

    <StackPanel Margin="20,0">
      <RadioButton x:Name="rbHeader1" IsChecked="True" Content="RB1" />
      <RadioButton x:Name="rbHeader2" Content="RB2"/>
      <RadioButton x:Name="rbHeader3" Content="RB3"/>
      <RadioButton x:Name="rbHeader4" Content="RB4"/>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnExport" Content="Export"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <DataGrid x:Name="DGV" Width="637" FontWeight="Bold" 
              AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" AlternationCount="2" RowBackground="#FFC6C6C6"  
              CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              MinColumnWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" "/>
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="URL" Width="295"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Width="80"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 2" Width="80"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 3" Width="80"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

  </StackPanel>
  <!-- End Row 0 -->

  <!-- Grid.Row="1" would go here if there was something to go here, 
       otherwise this cell row just expands the available height and 
       pushes the footer row to the bottom to provide that area of
       white space -->

  <!-- Begin Row 2 -->
  <Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF313130" />
        <GradientStop Offset="0.31" Color="#FFD8D8CF" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FF757672" />
        <GradientStop Offset="0.203" Color="#FFD8D8CF" />
        <GradientStop Offset="0.547" Color="#FFBABAAF" />
        <GradientStop Color="White" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
  <!-- End Row 3 -->

  <!-- Begin Row 3 -->
  <Grid Grid.Row="3" Height="28" Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- TextBlock is "lighter" than Label, use it instead where you can. -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock x:Name="label1"
                 Text="Find:" />
      <TextBox x:Name="txtSearchTerm"
               Margin="8,0" Width="130"/>
      <Button x:Name="btnFind"
              Width="60"
              Content="Find Next"/>
      <Button x:Name="btnFindPrevious"
                Width="100" Margin="10,0"
                Content="Find Previous"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <CheckBox x:Name="chkMatchCase"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Content="Match Case"/>

    <CheckBox x:Name="chkWholeWord"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Content="Whole Word"/>

    <CheckBox x:Name="chkSearchBackwards"
              Grid.Column="3"
              Content="Search Backwards"/>

    <CheckBox x:Name="chkWrapSearch"
              Grid.Column="4"
              Content="Wrap"/>

    <CheckBox x:Name="chkHiLitAll"
              Grid.Column="5"
              Content="HiLite All Occurrences"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="6" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <!-- These Previous/Next things were labels, were they supposed to be buttons
           since they have a "Hand" cursor? -->
      <TextBlock x:Name="lblPrevious" Text="Previous" Cursor="Hand"/>
      <CheckBox x:Name="cbGood" Content="Good" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
      <CheckBox x:Name="cbNotsure" Content="Not sure" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
      <CheckBox x:Name="cbBad" Content="Bad" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
      <TextBlock x:Name="lblNext" Text="Next" Cursor="Hand"/>
    </StackPanel>

  </Grid>
  <!-- End Row 3 -->

  <!-- Begin Row 4 -->
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblStatusText"
               Text="{Binding CurrentBrowser.StatusText, FallbackValue=Status Text}"
               Margin="5"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblSecurityStatus"/>
  </StackPanel>
  <!-- End Row 4 -->

  <!-- I didn't see this in your image, so wasn't sure where it goes -->
  <!-- 
  <Border x:Name="NewTabButton">
    <Image x:Name="btnNewTab"
           ToolTip="Add New Tab">
           <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
           </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
  </Border>
  -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did that work out for you? I did it in a bit of a hurry last night.

Comment: Cool, well if you want to share more specifics offline or something we can get you sorted out one way or another. Cheers

Comment: No I did minor edits to integrate it in my full design code, but what you provided worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though your main problem is not using the concept of margins correctly.

I'd recommend reading tutorials such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx

http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html

to see the variety of layout panels available and how to implement them.